# How can I randomly pull out a String from an array list and put it in another?

Tags: java

As seen in the code that I tried to write, I want to grab a name from the Array list "names" and either add it to groupA or B. I do not need the groups to be even.

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException; 
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GroupPicker{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("GroupPicker1.txt"));
        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> groupA = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> groupB = new ArrayList<String>();
        Random random = new Random();
        while(input.hasNext()){
            String nextName = input.next();
            names.add(nextName);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++) {
          names.get(random.nextInt(groupA.add()));
          
          names.get(random.nextInt(groupB.add()));
        }
        System.out.println( "\n" + "project groups: ");
        System.out.println("Group A: " + groupA);
        System.out.println("Group B: " + groupB);   
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "if harry goes into group A he can not go into group B." ? Because if you take Harry from names into group A, how could you pull him out once again from group A ? Unless you're talking about multiple Harry ?

Comment: Do the groups need to be the same length at the end?  What if one group has 10 people and the other group 0 because of the random chance?

Comment: @Zabon I didn't think about that. So could I have a randomly add in the same loop, I don't need the groups to be even(in terms of size)

Comment: @Nexevis I Don't need the groups to be even

Comment: The code in your question does not compile. Method [add](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(E)), in class `java.util.ArrayList`, requires an argument. I am referring to this line of the code in your question: `names.get(random.nextInt(groupA.add()));`

Comment: I think what you want is to go through each name and randomly decided whether to add it to `groupA` or `groupB`, and I'd suggest coding it that way.

Comment: It needs a random between `i` and the size of the list anyway

Comment: @Taylor with the for loop, am I not doing that? it's going by 1 by 1, and then either sending the name to A or B

Comment: No, you're randomly getting a name from the list and adding to a group, twice per name in the list.  You could end up with the two lists, each the size of your names list, all with the same name. Kemper Lee's answer below has the right solution, imo

Answer (score 1):

> How can I randomly pull out a String from an array list and put it in another

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
Random r = new Random();
```

- `nextInt(n)` - returns a value between `0 and n-1` inclusive
- `r.nextInt(names.size())` - will get one random index of all possible indices

```
String name = names.get(r.nextInt(names.size());
List<String> otherList = new ArrayList<>();
otherList.add(name);
```

Note you can also shuffle a list if required.

```
Collections.shuffle(names);
```

Then you can simply iterate across the list, getting names in the new random  order.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to make sure the `random.nextInt()` doesn't give you a too high value, because you only put so much values into `names`, but `random.nextInt()` will return any int - this could be even negative!

So the easiest way would be this:

1. shuffle the `names` list with `Collections.shuffle(names)`
2. put the first half of `names` into `groupA` - with the use of `List.subList` you would not even have to create a new list, just use the returned result.
3. put the second half of `names` into `groupB`

You have to take care about the indexes for the "halfes" - and decide what to do if the number of entries in `names` is odd - put one more into `groupA` or `groupB`.

Answer (score 1):

When I read this problem, two conditions stand out.

1. the names must go into one of the lists (meaning not the other)
   -- you must take it from the names ArrayList
2. the names do not need to be even
   -- you do not need to keep track of which list they are being added to

I would use an enhanced for-loop for ease of use (the less variables the better)

```
    // this cycles through each index of the names ArrayList
    for(String singleName : names)
    {
        // creates a random number
        java.util.Random number = new java.util.Random();

        // add to groupA if it is an even number and groupB if it is odd
        if(number.nextInt(2) % 2 == 0)
            groupA.add(singleName);
        else
            groupB.add(singleName);
    }
```

**EDIT AFTER SHOWING MY PROFF XD**

For simplicities sake, you could even cut off the `% 2 == 0` because **0** and **1** will only ever give you **0** or **1** with that statement. This could look like this:

```
    java.util.Random rand = new java.util.Random();
    // true = one list && false = the other
    if(rand.nextBoolean())
        groupA.add(singleName);
    else
        groupB.add(singleName);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I would do if I understand your need :

```java
// Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("GroupPicker1.txt"));
      String arr[] = new String[] { "A", "B", "C", "D" };
      ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(arr));
      ArrayList<String> groupA = new ArrayList<String>();
      ArrayList<String> groupB = new ArrayList<String>();
      
      // while(input.hasNext()){
      //     String nextName = input.next();
      //     names.add(nextName);
      // }
      while (!names.isEmpty()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++) {
          int random = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(i, names.size());
          boolean randBool = Math.random() < 0.5;
          String name = names.get(random);
          names.remove(random);
          if (randBool){ 
            groupA.add(name);
            break;
          };
          groupB.add(name);
        }  
      }
      
      System.out.println( "\n" + "project groups: ");
      System.out.println("Group A: " + groupA);
      System.out.println("Group B: " + groupB);
```